# Java Swing - Detect which display a JFrame is displayed on

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I am aware from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704208/java-keep-window-fullscreen-in-second-monitor-when-not-focused) that you can get the current displays as a `GraphicsDevice[]` in a swing application with the following code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

I understand that from here I could set the device myself, let the user select which to use in a menu, etc.  My goal is to detect which of these GraphicsDevices the application is currently displayed in, so I can default to fullscreening in that current GraphicsDevice without bothering the user.

I am using code like the following to fullscreen my application:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

// ... when I want to fullscreen:
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()){
    frame.dispose();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I cannot find anything in the GraphicsDevice or GraphicsEnvironment APIs to get the current GraphicsDevice the JFrame is displayed on.  I am aware there may be possible hacks by positioning the window directly (as described in the link above), but I am wondering if there is an easier/more elegant solution.

Comment: Generally I simply use the `GraphicsConfiguration`s of the `GraphicsDevice`s to test if the Window is within the bounds of the device, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158548/how-to-figure-out-on-which-screen-a-jdialog-is-shown/12170555#12170555)

Comment: Awesome, so I can measure which device the window overlaps with the greatest area?

Comment: Yeah, the example (`getGraphicsDevice(Component)`) does that too ;)

Comment: Check out Santhosh's answer.  Works perfectly, just like the code example you wrote (which works too), but why reinvent the wheel when it is already in the API?

Comment: the likely reason is because it either didn't do what I wanted or didn't return the results I wanted or expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
GraphicsDevice device = jframe.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice()
```

Comment: Wow, that is super simple!  How did I not see that before

Comment: I use Intellij Idea. GraphicsDevice device = frame.<ctrl_shift_space,ctrl_shift_space> magically completes giving me the answer

Comment: I have used Intellij's Android Studio, and the IDE has a lot of really nice features, good to know a new one!